# How can I speed up this image mask creation process in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, parallel-processing, gpu

I need to create masks for 100.000 images, this code runs on cpu and creates ~500 masks a hour. Is there a way I can speed this up either by parallelising or running code on gpu? I'm okay with solutions that make me heavily rewrite code as long as it speeds up the process.

I tried compiling opencv library myself with cuda support, however I couldn't get most of cv2 methods I use here to run on gpu.

This is my code

Edit #1

Added import list and comments to code.

Added input and output images.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import glob
import sys
import os
import skimage.color
import skimage.filters
import skimage.io
import skimage.viewer


grayScale = cv2.imread(filename,cv2.IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_4)#read image as grayscale with size reduction

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(1,(17,17))

blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(grayScale, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, kernel)

ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(blackhat,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

dst = cv2.inpaint(newimg,thresh2,1,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)  #4 lines above are used to remove hair from image

mask = np.zeros(dst.shape[:2],np.uint8)

h,w,c = dst.shape

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

rect = (int(0.1*w),int(0.1*h),int(0.8*w),int(0.8*h))

cv2.grabCut(dst,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,1,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT) #removes some background from image
#code for k means clustering starts here

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')

dst = dst*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

vectorized = dst.reshape((-1,3))

vectorized = np.float32(vectorized)

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0) #11 lines above are used to remove some background from image

K = 4 
attempts=1

  ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(vectorized,K,None,criteria,attempts,cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS)

center = np.uint8(center)

labels = label.flatten()

res = center[label.flatten()]

result_image = res.reshape((dst.shape)) #k means clustering ends here

gray = cv2.cvtColor(result_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 10, 20, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

result_image[thresh == 0] = 255

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))

erosion = cv2.erode(result_image, kernel, iterations = 1)

blur = skimage.color.rgb2gray(erosion)

blur = skimage.filters.gaussian(blur, sigma=float(1)) 

histogram, bin_edges = np.histogram(blur, bins=256, range=(0, 1))

index = next((i for i, x in enumerate(histogram) if x), None)

mask = blur > bin_edges[index+1] #10 lines above are used to create mask

mask = abs(mask-255) #inverts mask

array = np.array(mask, dtype='uint8') 

finimg = cv2.resize(array,None,fx=4.0,fy=4.0) #returns image to original size

plt.imsave("Masks/"+filename, finimg, cmap = plt.cm.gray) #saves result image
```

[input image - skin mole image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otSbO.jpg)
[output image - mask of skin mole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXirA.jpg)

Comment: This involves only image processing. Multiprocessing will help. They have used multiprocessing : https://github.com/ocropus/ocropy/blob/master/ocropus-nlbin

Comment: I suspect you might get a better response if you described what you were trying to do, and provided some benchmarks/timing of the various parts, rather than dumping a load of poorly formatted, uncommented code. I only read part way through your code as I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but you should maybe look at `cv2.IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_4` as parameter to your `imread()` as that will significantly reduce I/O and memory load. You should also benchmark and see where the time is going. Also, look at multiprocessing if you have a decent CPU+RAM+disk.

Comment: Why have you removed your `import` statements? Kindly provide representative input and output images if asking questions about image processing.

Comment: @Pygirl got multiprocessing to work thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Added some comments about what code does, input, output images, got multiprocessing to work and now I'm using suggested parameter in imread(). Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You might try using kmeans processing in Python/Opencv as a first step. Then get the inner contour and use that for your mask. Draw the inner contour as white filled on a black background. You may need to use morphology to clean the kmeans results first

Input:

[image]

Kmeans 2:

[image]

Kmeans 3:

[image]

Kmeans 4:

[image]